# JPA Cast is not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I have a table `person{id,personName,birthDate}`. In the table I have to get all the person details by their birthDate with out comparing its time. I have the following query

```
Query q = entitymanager.createQuery(select p from person p where
    CAST(p.birthDate as date) = :birthdate);         
q.setparameter("birthdate",new Date(),TemporalType.DATE) ;
```

When I test the above query using mysql, it gives the correct result. But it is not functioning correctly in Oracle. I tried the `between...and` logic by setting the starting time as 0:0:0 and the ending time as 23:59:59. Is there any other alternative.

I am using JPA 1.0 with hibernate as a service provider. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `where trunc(p.birthDate) = :birthdate`

Comment: @ Egor Skriptunoff still that is not working

Comment: @ Egor Skriptunoff Is trunc supported by JPA

Comment: trunc is not supported by JPA. You can use Between...And. But I think you code is the way of JPA to achieve it.